# XML response to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, xml-parsing, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm using UrlFetchApp.fetch to get an API data base of contacts, the response is an unformatted XML. I want to create a spreadsheet using this data Eg, Names(Column A), Company(Column B) etc. The response is 50 items formatted like this:

```
<item><rating>0</rating><resume_preview/><candidate_id>97096654</candidate_id><name>Bradley Johnston</name><location>Bentley, WA</location><source>Company Referral</source><added>09-09-14</added><last_activity>09-09-14 (Heath C.): Added candidate to pipeline: Potential</last_activity><status>Potential</status><status_historical> </status_historical><action/><title>Engineering & IT</title><company>Internal Postings</company><item_id>61571959</item_id></item><item><rating>0</rating><resume_preview/><candidate_id>97274234</candidate_id><name>Jacksen Dulvarie</name><location>Ivanhoe, VIC</location><source>Careers Website</source><added>10-09-14</added><last_activity>18-09-14 (Andrew V.): Status change: Potential</last_activity><status>Potential</status><status_historical> </status_historical><action/><title>Law</title><company>Internal Postings</company><item_id>61627337</item_id></item>
```

Each "Item" or person has fields: rating, resume_preview, candidate_id, name, location, source... etc, then "Item" and it goes again.

I want a row for each item and for them to be in their corresponding column headers.

Maybe an array of names etc then write to a column?

```
function loadOutposts(){"http://api.catsone.com/api/get_pipelines.....";


  var parameters = {method : "get", payload : ""};
  var xmlFeed = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters).getContentText();
  var outposts= new Array();
  var url = 
  var document = XmlService.parse(xmlFeed);



 var document = XmlService.parse(xmlFeed); 
 logChildren(document.getRootElement().getChildren());



}


function logChildren(elements){
 Logger.log(elements.length);
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  Logger.log("%s -> %s",elements[i].getName(),elements[i].getText());
  if(elements[i].getContentSize() > 1){
    var children = elements[i].getChildren();

    logChildren(children);
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting?